# Sum of series where the general term is a rational expression of the index.

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain how to resolve this without Wolfram Alpha:

Find a closed-form formula for

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n + 5}{n^3 + 7 n^2 + 14 n + 8}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For help, you can first factor the denominator, as $(n+1)(n+2)(n+4)$, and then apply partial fraction decomposition on the fraction.

Comment: Continuing the hint of @Sahaj Satish Sharma, your general term is $(1/6)/(n + 4) - (3/2)/(n + 2) + (4/3)/(n + 1)$ : observe that a lot of cancellations take place...

Comment: Thank you, I managed to reach this form but I can’t see the cancellations.

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma how did you find that ?

Comment: @pie you have many ways to factor a cubic. For this cubic you can find all three roots via rational root theorem.

Answer (score 4):

See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions)

Infinite series where the term is a rational function may be evaluate in terms of the [**digamma** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions) $\psi(n)$.  Perhaps to consider the answer to be "closed form", we must factor the denominator into linear terms (possibly with complex coefficients).

I this case, we factor the denominator $(n+1)(n+2)(n+4)$ and use partial fractions:
$$
\frac{n + 5}{n^3 + 7 n^2 + 14 n + 8}
=\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{n+4} .
$$
We will use the basic formulas
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n+c} = \psi(N+c)-\psi(c)
\\
\text{(in particular)}\qquad\psi(n+1)=\psi(n)+\frac{1}{n}
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{n + 5}{n^3 + 7 n^2 + 14 n + 8} =
\frac{4}{3}\psi(N+1)-\frac{3}{2}\psi(N+2)+\frac{1}{6}\psi(N+4)+\frac{43}{36}
\\=
-\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{N+2}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{N+3}
+\frac{43}{63}
$$
(We used Gauss's formula for the value of $\psi(c)$ with $c$ rational.)
Limit says
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n + 5}{n^3 + 7 n^2 + 14 n + 8} = \frac{43}{63} .
$$

Comment: I think in your $N$th partial sum it should be $\psi(c)-\psi(N+c)$ (reverse order of what you have).  But this won't effect the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Doug But $\psi$ is increasing, so to get a positive number (when $c>0$) we want $\psi(N+c)-\psi(c)$.

Comment: Ok.  My mistake.